# How can I color-map the curve one in relative to the curve two?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use the color mapping base on distance of two curve. For example, How is it possible to color-map curve 1 base on the distance which is shown in the figure.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[thick] {10*sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[thick] {x^2/2+17};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} ‎
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `point meta` option with a custom expression for calculating the color of the curve:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot[mesh,thick,point meta=37-x^2-10*sin(deg(x)),colormap/redyellow] {10*sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[thick] {-x^2+37};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The colors can be changed with the `colormap` option.